# In general relativity vizualizations what are the equations of grids?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, computational-physics, geodesics, visualization

I am wondering what curved 3D grids in GR outreach correspond to in equations. How would I compute such a curved grid if I know the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ in every point of space? What would be the equation of a line of that grid? What is the physical interpretation of such a grid (what are we really visualizing)?

[image: 3D1]
[image: 3D2]

EDIT: Maybe the question was not clear enough. I know that spacetime is in 4D. I am ok to reduce the problem to 2D, 3D, ... I am wondering how you go from a metric tensor to a curved line so that, with the right projection your could obtain something that resemble these kinds of grids. My guess is that most of these grids are made with 3D software like blender without any metric tensor being involved at any point during the design. But let's say I have the metric tensor, how could I reproduce something which resemble what is depicted in these figures from an actual equation (even if I know it's not perfect and we would need more dimensions).

Comment: I'm not sure, as I've never actually seen these sorts of things before.  They might be just meaningless artists' impressions, but they might be something more.  A little more context about the claims being made in the sources from which they're taken might help us understand.

Comment: There is no standard definition or concept of what those grids are. It depends on what whoever made the visualizations wanted to picture.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the physical interpretation of such a grid (what are we really visualizing)?

I suppose it is an attempt to show how massive objects "contract" spacetime towards themselves which results in gravity, but in reality that's not what's happening at all (for starters, the contraction is not static, it's shrinking constantly).

> How would I compute such a curved grid if I know the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ in every point of space?

You can't. Spacetime is a 4-dimensional manifold. It can never be properly shown in 3-dimensional space while preserving all 3 spatial dimensions. The images you linked are not good depictions of (I presume Schwarzschild spacetime) at all because they ignore the most important part which is the time dimension. The curvature is, colloquially speaking, happening in the temporal and radial dimensions. As all objects travel forward in time, the curvature bends their spacetime trajectories, rotating temporal velocity into spatial velocity toward each other, bringing them spatially closer to each other.

In addition, the metric components depend not only on the spacetime but also on the coordinate system. Different coordinate systems correspond roughly to different observers. Different coordinate systems result in different "grids" covering the same spacetime.

Much better visualizations will be something like [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.2483) or [this](https://jila.colorado.edu/%7Eajsh/bh/schwp.html). These are much better because they actually consider time. ScienceClic also has a very good [video](https://youtu.be/wrwgIjBUYVc) explaining why these pop science visualizations are ultimately incorrect while providing a good alternative that's similar to the ones you linked. It actually includes the constant contraction I mentioned at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Depictions of coordinate systems typically contain a set of geodesic with each coordinate held to a sequence of constant values. Cartesian coordinates are straight lines in flat space and equal time displacements. Polar coordinates are a series of circles of different radius, with points at a sequence of angles, lines connecting different radii and constant angles, stepped in a sequence of z coordinates, etc. A metric can be expressed in all kinds of different coordinates, so given a metric, you also have to decide what coordinate system to express that metric in order to produce a grid. Once you've done that, compute a sequence of geodesics with a constant set of displacements in each coordinate. This is done all the time in Computational Fluid Dynamics (in 2D or 3D) where it's called surface-fitted grids. Solution adaptive grids are generated by computing the second derivative of something like Mach number and using that to compute a metric. The grid is then generated by incrementing coordinates individually along geodesics.